# Installing Redmine on UBUNTU 14.04. No Apache in PERL

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, redmine

Im trying to install Redmine on my Ub 14.04 server, I did follow all the steps I tought to take, but then when I try to load the Redmine.pm library, Im getting an not found error.
(Command: ln -s /opt/redmine/current/extra/svn/Redmine.pm /usr/lib/perl5/Apache2/)

Turns out, there is no Apache2/apache2 folder or whatsoever in /usr/lib/perl5/

Is it because of 14.04, am I doing things wrong or is it just the devil trying to annoy me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [libapache2-mod-perl2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libapache2-mod-perl2), which provides [that directory](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libapache2-mod-perl2/filelist).